# Folder shortcuts on desktop

Tags: directory, shortcuts

Why do I have to reset my folder shortcuts (photos...documents...etc) after every boot-up or restart? Theres an X on each one and I have to go back redo them.

Comment: If on a drive/partition that isn't being mounted automatically then that happens but not a reset. Solution is add it to the fstab or use Disks for editing the mount options.

Comment: Ok...forgive me...I am still fairly new to Linux and I actually have about a million questions.  And some of these things make absolutely no sense to me.  Why do I have to tell my system to mount my drives automatically...I just want to put 3 or 4 shortcuts on my desktop.  Now theres an actual procedure for something that basic and simple??  Yes. I've come across a bunch of little things like this that seem ridiculous to me.  Heres another favorite.  Right click a jpg...ANY jpg...make it my desktop background...reboot...its gone...back to default background.   Lets me guess...more procedure.

Comment: You're used to a certain OS way of doing things, of dumbing down lots of processes that advanced users of proper OSes like to have some control over. The additional partitions not being mounted automatically and only when the OS has been explicitly told to do so used to be the norm. Now, due to popular demand and very much against the wishes of those old advanced users, Ubuntu automatically mounts external drives when detected but internal partition still aren't mounted automatically. You can easily change that with Disks > (...)

Comment: (...) > Select the partition, click the cogwheel > Edit mount point (something like that, mine isn't in English) > switch off the toggle switch, tick mount at boot... You can leave all the other option in the default but I suggest selecting LABEL in the identification field as it provides a user friendly name instead of GUID, etc.